# print(object.method) not printing expected output?

Tags: python, oop

I'm having a foray into OOP in python,

This project is creating some randomly generated RPG characters

The problem I have run into is I am creating a list of these randomly generated characters, and want to print out there stats.

Here is how the characters are randomly generated:

```
def generateCharacters():
    classes = ["B", "E", "W", "D", "K"]

    choice = random.choice(classes)

    if choice == "B":
        return barbarian(70, 20, 50)
    elif choice == "E":
        return elf(30, 60, 10)
    elif choice == "W":
        return wizard(50, 70, 30)
    elif choice == "D":
        return dragon(90, 40, 50)
    elif choice == "K":
        return knight(60, 10, 60)
```

and here is the barbarian class, all the other classes are more or less identical:

```
class barbarian(character):
    def __init__(self, charPower, charSAttackPwr, charSpeed):
        # Getting the properties from the inheritted character Base Class
        character.__init__(self, "B", 100)
        self.power = charPower
        self.sAttackPwr = charSAttackPwr
        self.speed = charSpeed

    # Method for getting and returning all the stats of the character
    def getStats(self):
        # Creating a string to hold all the stats, using concatenation
        stats = "Name: %s, Type: %s, Health: %s, Power: %s, Special Attack 
        Power: %s, Speed: %s" % (self.name, self.type, self.health, 
        self.power, self.sAttackPwr, self.speed)
        # Returns stats to the the function that called
        return stats
```

I've created a method called getStats, which using string concatenation to make a string that shows all the stats:

```
# Method for getting and returning all the stats of the character
def getStats(self):
    # Creating a string to hold all the stats, using concatenation
    stats = "Name: %s, Type: %s, Health: %s, Power: %s, Special Attack Power: %s, Speed: %s" % (self.name, self.type, self.health, self.power, self.sAttackPwr, self.speed)
    # Returns stats to the the function that called
    return stats
```

When I run the code, it calls main(), which in turn calls menu():

```
def menu(gameChars):
    print("Welcome to the RPG Character Simulator")
    print("Here is your randomly generated team: ")
    for x in gameChars:
        print(x.getStats)


def main():
    gameChars = []

    for x in range(10):
        y = generateCharacters()
        gameChars.insert(x, y)

    #z = generateCharacters()
    menu(gameChars)
    #print(z.getStats)
```

The output I was expecting from the print(x.getStats) would've been, using examples:

```
Name: bob, Type: barbarian, Health: 100, Power: 70, Special Attack Power: 20, Speed: 20
```

but instead, I get this:

```
<bound method barbarian.getStats of <__main__.barbarian object at 0x000001F56A195668>>
```

What am I missing with this? and how could I get the intended output?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `getStats` is a *function*, you have to call it like any other function, so `x.getStats()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this :

```
print(x.getStats)
```

With this :

```
print(x.getStats())
```

Comment: Ahh yeah... I knew it'd be something simply, I'm an idiot xD ty :)

Answer (score 0):

another version would be to use the `@property` decorator:

```
class Barbarian(Character):
  @property
  def getStats(self):
    return 'Name: {.name}'.format(self)
```

which would allow:

```
bob = Barbarian('bob', …)
print(bob.getStats)
```

to work as you expect